# using customised gevent server with flask

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I'm trying to control a few hardware on a raspberry pi, and run a gevent server to enable getting/setting of them over the web. As background, I should note this won't be run over the public internet, and will never have more than 1 connection. Think of it like building an admin panel for an adsl router....

The application is going to be continuously reading from a sensor and adjusting an output accordingly. At the moment I have something like this:

```
class MyServer(WSGIServer):

    somevalue = 0

    def backgroundtask(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #note this function should run as frequently as possible 
        while True:
            # do stuff including reading sensors and running motors
            self.somemethod(self.somevalue)
            gevent.sleep(0)

    def __init__(self, listener, handle=None, **kwargs):
        WSGIServer.__init__(self, listener, **kwargs)
        self.backgroundtask = gevent.spawn(self.backgroundtask)

    def application(self, environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        headers = [
            ('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        ]

        yield str(self.somevalue)
```

This works OK, and I could set `somevalue` from an incoming request if I parse environ, but what I'd like is to be able to have a Flask app get and set `somevalue` on this server so I can use all the standard form handling stuff.

Is this possible? How can I made `app=Flask(__name__)` be the server's application without losing access to `self` properties of the server?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a method queried by a client, and then printing out and change it again.

Using accessible by two routes client:

- / GetVar (eg php achievement: ht tp://IP:2020/getVar/)
- / SetVar (eg php achievement: ht tp://IP:2020/setVar/)

Php client code:

```
$url = 'http://IP:2020/setVar/';
$data = array('Var' => 9);
RunScript($data, $url);

function RunScript($data, $url) {
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print $result;  
}
```

Flask server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

somevalue = '?'
#********************************************************** Routs *****************************************************

@app.route('/setVar/', methods=['POST'])
def set_Var():
    try:
        global somevalue
        somevalue = request.form['Var']
        print 'Newvalue: ' + str(somevalue)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    return ''

@app.route('/getVar/', methods=['POST'])
def get_Var():
    global somevalue
    print somevalue
    return somevalue

#********************************************************** Routs end *************************************************
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=2020)
```

Run the console: 
[image: Run the console:]

On the client side:
[image: On the client side:]

I hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer — I've up voted you, but haven't accepted it because it seems like it might be vulnerable to race conditions where what I called the backgroundtask tries to set a global at the same time as the user input.  In the end I solved the problem using an actor model similar to the one described here: http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/#actors